# Security of sanitized user content served from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, xss

First I will describe by case:

I am building app using angular and firebase. Angular client has input, where user can write some custom content and I wanted this content to be reach text *aka* markdown/html to allow [links](https://stackoverflow.com), **bold**, *italic* etc...

Content of this input is saved in firebase database and later loaded back to other users - basically you can imagine this as simple case of stack overflow question.

As we know any content served by client is not safe, it means it is possible to create XSS attack if backend do not sanitize content of this message.
Serving any message from firebase can be dangerous but as I use angular brackets, then the content of my `{{ message }}` should be escaped and message like this:
`my message and <script> evilScript(); </script>` should be served as it is.

Now, lets say we don't use plain text messages but html or markdown. In this case it's completely normal to see content like:

- `**hello** it is me`
- `<strong>hello</strong> it is me`

but this time I can't serve it as it is. I can't allow serving pure html because this is not safe for end-user. In case of markdown I have to transform it to html first so this is almost the same case 
(except I just do one additional step). Simply speaking in this case I have to sanitize message first.

#### How to handle this?

As firebase just stores informations in database I can only secure my app in end user angular client. In this case is it good idea to sanitize user messages just when they arrive from firebase? Is it secure?
Is there anyway to deceive angular app when content is checked just before serving? If yes, can you show me example and tell me how to handle this case?

Comment: It is fairly common to render the markup you show into HTML in the client. That can be done securely, but there's also ways to mess that up of course (e.g. by using `innerHTML` in the raw text). Without seeing your code, it is impossible to way whether your approach is secure or not.

Comment: Understand, I tried to ask if general approach is ok. Simply if there is any way to "hack it" if server message gonna be purified by some library and then served as raw html (no escaping). If this is common to do this, then why everyone use markup/bbcode instead of pure html if message content can be purifed anyway just before putting it into page?

Comment: Whether a library is safe, depends on the library. bbcode and markdown are typically converted into HTML before displaying them to the user. Some sites do this client-side, others do it server-side, and some (such as Stack Overflow) even do it both client- and server-side.

Comment: I mean, this is for me obvious - using some lib for both sides is the best but in this case I can't do anything from datebase side (or at least this is not easy) so I was curious if this is bassicaly safe. anyway thank you for some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the content through DOMPurify before adding it to the DOM (through angular). It will make sure the HTML is static (contains no active code) and DOMPurify has been created by some of the world’s best XSS researchers.
https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Comment: This is sure usefull but my question was a little more about "is it secure to do like this" instead of what library should I use. Obviously any software can have some security vulnerability but except this, is it safe to do like this?

Comment: Yes, you need to sanitize when it comes back from firebase, because that's the point when you know where it should be rendered (what if a later time you alter the HTML, migrate to react or vue or something like that). And the best way to sanitize it is to use DOMPurify before rendering it with angular :)